# Couldn't find preset "flow" relative to directory

Tags: react-native, flowtype

Strange it seems that I am the first person to experience this "flow" preset error on the interwebz..

My `.babelrc` is configured as

```
{
  presets: ["react-native", "flow"]
}
```

My package.json includes the following dev dependencies:

```
{
  "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
  "flow-bin": "^0.38.0"
}
```

Yet I'm receiving the following error:

```
TransformError: /Users/Progoogler/App/ios/src/index.js: Couldn't find 
preset "flow" relative to directory "/Users/Progoogler/App"
```

Has anyone experienced this problem before with flow?

Comment: Did you actively `npm install babel-preset-flow` or just edit your `package.json`?

Comment: You're right. I was missing babel-preset-flow. I thought `npm install` had installed every dependency... but separately running `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-flow` actually installed it. Thank you!